# Uncertainty in a program using Struct and pointer (C language program)

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

typedef struct WFC_STRUCT {
int a;
int b;
} WFC_STRUCT;

WFC_STRUCT *ptr = (WFC_STRUCT*) NULL;

ptr->a=10;


return(0);

}
```

I would like to understand what is happening at instruction:

```
WFC_STRUCT *ptr = (WFC_STRUCT*) NULL;
```

Why the program is breaking? In what cases the instruction above is used?.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Don't cast a null pointer constant like represented by the `NULL` macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WFC_STRUCT *ptr = (WFC_STRUCT*) NULL; // cast is unnessesary
//moreover you have no memory alloacted

WFC_STRUCT *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr); // allocates memory, if this is done
//then you can do below
ptr->a=10;
```

---

<sup>Do check [[ this ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1620779) answer on how to use pointers</sup>

Comment: why not `malloc(sizeof(WFC_STRUCT))` ?

Comment: @artm `malloc(sizeof *ptr)` is binding in nature.. You don't have to count the stars when having  `pointer to pointer` and so. So less chance of error..

Comment: I always use `sizeof(struct)`, but you are probably correct too

Comment: @sjsam Thanks for explanation.

Comment: @artm : Kindly check [\[ this \]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1620779) which gives a nice explanation.

Comment: @sjsam I remember not to cast, but didn't notice the `sizeof(*pointer)` style ;) cheers

Answer (score 6):

Although the cast in this line

```
WFC_STRUCT *ptr = (WFC_STRUCT*) NULL;
```

is useless, the actual problem is in the next line:

```
ptr->a=10; /* This is equivalent to: (*ptr).a=10; */
```

where, you dereference a NULL pointer. It's [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Basically, `ptr` should be pointing at valid/writable memory location. But in your code, it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

A `pointer` is a variable that holds the location of, literally the address-of, a variable stored in computer memory. Dereferencing a pointer means getting the value stored in the memory at the address which the pointer “points” to.

So, to access structure individual members using a pointer to that structure, your pointer variable should point to some valid memory address at which memory is allocated to a structure variable.

But `ptr` pointer to structure `WFC_STRUCT` in your program doesn't point to a valid structure variable of type `WFC_STRUCT` in the valid memory address space. So, there is no point to access structure variable using `ptr`.

Also, `WFC_STRUCT *ptr = (WFC_STRUCT*) NULL` cast is unnessesary.

If you want to access a structure variable using pointer, you can do this in two ways:

```
WFC_STRUCT *ptr = malloc(sizeof(WFC_STRUCT));
```

OR

```
WFC_STRUCT *ptr;
WFC_STRUCT var;

ptr = &var;
ptr->a = 20;
```

Remenber, if you allocate some memory space using `malloc` function call, you need to call `free` function to deallocate the memory space when it is not needed anymore. However, in the second method, as variables are created over stack, all the `automatic` variable will be destroyed as function returns.

Answer (score 0):

`WFC_STRUCT *ptr = (WFC_STRUCT*) NULL;`  is simply assigning address 0 (which is value of `NULL`) to `ptr`.  It is common practice to assign `NULL` to a newly created pointer.

Now, accessing values using a pointer which points to `0th` address is not allowed on most operating systems, hence the program is breaking.

If you really want to assign value to `ptr->a` then `ptr` should point to proper memory location.

```
WFC_STRUCT *ptr = (WFC_STRUCT*) malloc(sizeof(WFC_STRUCT));
ptr->a = 10;
free(ptr); // remember to free the allocated memory
ptr = NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation.